# Program to print the number as a sum of consecutives

Tags: java

> We need the input number as the sum of consecutive natural numbers.
>
> Examples:
>
> For input 27, output should be:
>
> 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> 8 9 10
>
> 13 14
>
> For input 9, the output should be:
>
> 4 5
>
> 2 3 4

Here is my code. It works as it is expected to:

```
import java.util.*;
class Consecutives
{
    static void print()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        double n = sc.nextDouble(); 
        /*
         * Needed: Different Arithmetic progressions (APs) with common difference 1; 
         * i(2a + (i-1)) = 2n // from formula for sum of AP, a indicates first term of progression
         * #implies -> a = n/i - (i-1)/2   // i indicates number of terms of AP possible
         * Now, a can't be negative so: 
         * -> n/i > (i-1)/2
         * -> Range of i = [2, (int)(1+sqrt(1+8n))/2] 
         */
        int max_i = (int)((1+Math.sqrt(1+8*n))/2);
        System.out.println("Max i = "+ max_i);
        double a; 
        for(double i=2; i <= max_i ;i++)
        {
            a = n/i - (i-1)/2; 
            if(a == Math.floor(a) && a>0)//i.e if a is an integer
            {

                if(i*(2*a+ (i-1))== 2*n)
                {
                    for(int j= (int)a ; j<=a + (i-1) ;j++)
                        System.out.print(j+ " ");
                    System.out.println(); 
                }
                else
                    break; 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Are my comments too messy? Is there any way to change them and still make the logic clear to the reader? What other improvements can I make to my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm, being \$O(\sqrt n)\$, is pretty efficient.  I just think that your code could just a bit of cleanup.

Your `print()` function does all kinds of things, mostly unrelated to printing.  You should separate the code for the user interaction from the calculation.  (Since each result is a pair of numbers, and there will be an indeterminate number of results, I'd use a callback.)  You should also extract the loop the prints each series into a helper function.  (Executing many `System.out.print()` statements can be surprisingly slow, as each one is a separate I/O operation.)

Your mathematical reasoning was not clear to me at first.  I would have preferred a comment that more clearly explained the nomenclature and used fewer words.

```
// n = a + (a+1) + ... + (a+i-1) (Given n, find all a>0 and i>=2)
//
// 2n = i(2a + (i-1))            (arithmetic series formula)
//
// a = (2n - i(i-1)) / 2i
//
// 2n > i(i-1)                   (because a>0 and i>0)
//
// 2 <= i < (1+sqrt(1+8n))/2     (quadratic formula)
```

Since this is supposed to be an exercise in integer arithmetic, you should avoid using doubles.  Use either `int` or `long`.  Note that I have avoided your `a = n/i - (i-1)/2`, which involves non-integer division.

Actually, you don't need to calculate `max_i`.  You don't really trust that bound, and you test for `a > 0` anyway.

### Suggested solution

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class Consecutives {
    /**
     * Find integers a>0 and i>=2 such that n = a + (a+1) + ... + (a+i-1).
     *
     * @param n        The target sum.
     * @param callback A function that will be called with parameters a and i
     *                 for each solution found.
     */
    public static void findSeries(long n, BiConsumer<Long, Long> callback) {
        // n = a + (a+1) + ... + (a+i-1) (Given n, find all a>0 and i>=2)
        //
        // 2n = i(2a + (i-1))            (arithmetic series formula)
        //
        // a = (2n - i(i-1)) / 2i

        for (long i = 2; ; i++) {
            long aNumer = 2 * n - i * (i - 1);
            long aDenom = 2 * i;
            if (aNumer <= 0) break;
            if (aNumer % aDenom == 0) {
                callback.accept(aNumer / aDenom, i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Form a string of all integers in the range [a, a+i), separated by space.
     */
    private static String spaceDelimitedRange(long a, long i) {
        return LongStream.range(a, a+i)
                         .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        findSeries(
            scanner.nextLong(),
            (a, i) -> System.out.println(spaceDelimitedRange(a, i))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which part of my mathematical reasoning isn't clear? Please let me know so that I can elaborate upon that.

Comment: I've made an effort to understand your reasoning, and completely rewrote my review in Rev 2.